# Rewrite rule if some string not exists in the uri

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect all the requests if some string not exists in the URI.

If I write this - redirect all requests, where the string "/clkf" exists, then everything works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clk\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/clkf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.de/ [L,R]
```

But when I want to make the oposite - redirect all other requests except this one, which are having the string "/clkf", then it is redirecting everything.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clk\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clkf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.de/ [L,R]
```

The End result should be:

```
http://clk.example.de -> https://www.example.de
http://clk.example.de/bla -> https://www.example.de
http://clk.example.de/clkf?adasd -> NOT REDIRECT
```

BTW: The rules are written in the Apache Vhost, not in a .htaccess file

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Use a different browser that you haven't used to access the site in question or clear the cache of your current one to ensure what you're seeing is not the result of a cache on 301, **also change your R to R=302 until you get the redirect right to avoid more caching.**

Comment: Your redirect is fine. In addition to the caching advice above you can use an incognito tab.